# After storing a document, how can i return the ID column value (Not the guid)

Tags: sharepoint-online

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;


namespace UploadSH365
{
    class UploadFile
    {
        public string Upload(string vURL, out string vURLout, string vUName,         string vPWD, string vList, string vFolder, string vFileName, byte[] vAttachment,     Dictionary<string, string> metadata, bool overwrite)
        {
            string strMsg = "";
            vURLout = "";
            string vDocID;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vURL))         
                return "Empty URL field";

            try
            {
                using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(vURL))
                {
                    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
                    foreach (char c in vPWD.ToCharArray())
                        passWord.AppendChar(c);

                    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(vUName, passWord);
                    Web web = clientContext.Web;

                    //clientContext.Load(folder);
                    //clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
                    newFile.Content = vAttachment;
                    newFile.Url = vFileName;
                    newFile.Overwrite = overwrite;

                    //Folder newfolder =     web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("NewFolder");
                    List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(vList);

                    // ListItem folder = web.GetListItem("NewFolder");
                    var newfolder = docs.RootFolder.Folders.Add(vFolder);

                    Folder folder = docs.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl(vFolder);                    

                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = folder.Files.Add(newFile);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery() ;

                    ListItem item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    item.File.CheckOut();
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> metadataitem in metadata)
                    {
                        item[metadataitem.Key.ToString()] = metadataitem.Value.ToString();
                    }

                    item.Update();
                    item.File.CheckIn("", CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    //Instert process to get ID column here
                    var vID = "";

                    //-------------------------------
                    vURLout = vID.ToString(); // vURL + "/" + vList + "/" + vFolder + "/" + vFileName;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strMsg = ex.Message;
            }

            return strMsg;
            // Console.ReadLine();
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added 3,4 lines of code, it will give you item id.

```
public string Upload(string vURL, out string vURLout, string vUName, string vPWD, string vList, string vFolder, string vFileName, byte[] vAttachment, Dictionary<string, string> metadata, bool overwrite)
        {


            string strMsg = "";
            vURLout = "";
            string vDocID;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vURL))

                return "Empty URL field";

            try
            {

                using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(vURL))
                {
                    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
                    foreach (char c in vPWD.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
                    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(vUName, passWord);
                    Web web = clientContext.Web;

                    //clientContext.Load(folder);
                    //clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


                    FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
                    newFile.Content = vAttachment;
                    newFile.Url = vFileName;
                    newFile.Overwrite = overwrite;



                    //Folder newfolder =     web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("NewFolder");
                    List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(vList);

                    // ListItem folder = web.GetListItem("NewFolder");
                    var newfolder = docs.RootFolder.Folders.Add(vFolder);


                    Folder folder = docs.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl(vFolder);


                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = folder.Files.Add(newFile);

                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    ListItem item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;



                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


                    item.File.CheckOut();
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> metadataitem in metadata)

                    {

                        item[metadataitem.Key.ToString()] = metadataitem.Value.ToString();

                    }



                    item.Update();
                    item.File.CheckIn("", CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);

                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    //Instert process to get ID column here

                    clientContext.Load(uploadFile, f => f.ListItemAllFields);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    //Print List Item Id
                    MessageBox.Show(uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Id.ToString());

                    var vID = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Id;



                    //-------------------------------


                    vURLout = vID.ToString(); // vURL + "/" + vList + "/" + vFolder + "/" + vFileName;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strMsg = ex.Message;
            }

            return strMsg;
            // Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Hope this helps..happy coding..!!!!

Comment: happy to help....if it solved your issue, please upvote and mark it as answer for other's reference....